# Checkmarx issue XS_Reflected_XSS

Tags: security, xss, hana, checkmarx, xsjs

I am facing a XS_Reflected_XSS issue related to Checkmarx. Working in SAP HANA XSJS.

Following is my code extract :

```
action = **$.request.parameters.get("action");**
        switch ($.request.method) {
        case $.net.http.GET:
            switch (action) {
            case "ds":
                res = aLib.getds();
                break;
```

It calls the $.request.parameters.get("action"); as a checkmarx issue.
Anyone knows how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Where else is the `action` variable used? Any instance of XSS would require the payload to be written out to the response or page, at some point, somehow...

Comment: @AviD Thanks boss. Got it. There was one more reference to action in the code removed it and the checkmarx was resolved.